# Page headers in RTF

Tags: xml, rtf, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I have some XML file which I need to transform into RTF. I also need to insert some text in header of first page.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:exslt="http://exslt.org/common" xmlns:str="http://exslt.org/strings" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" version="1.0">
    <xsl:template match="/">
            <xsl:call-template name="document" />
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="document">
    <fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
            <fo:layout-master-set>
                    <fo:simple-page-master margin-right="10mm" margin-left="20mm"
                    margin-bottom="5mm" margin-top="10mm" page-width="210mm"
                    page-height="297mm" master-name="first">
                            <fo:region-body margin-right="0mm" margin-left="0mm"
                            margin-bottom="10mm" margin-top="30mm" region-name="body" />
                            <fo:region-before extent="10mm" region-name="fheader" />
                            <fo:region-after extent="10mm"/>
                    </fo:simple-page-master>
                    <fo:simple-page-master margin-right="25mm" margin-left="10mm"
                    margin-bottom="5mm" margin-top="10mm" page-width="210mm"
                    page-height="297mm" master-name="rest">
                            <fo:region-body margin-right="0mm" margin-left="0mm"
                            margin-bottom="10mm" margin-top="10mm" region-name="body" />
                            <fo:region-before extent="10mm"/>
                            <fo:region-after extent="10mm"/>
                    </fo:simple-page-master>
                    <fo:page-sequence-master master-name="sequence">
                            <fo:repeatable-page-master-alternatives>
                                    <fo:conditional-page-master-reference master-reference="first" page-position="first"/>
                                    <fo:conditional-page-master-reference master-reference="rest" />
                            </fo:repeatable-page-master-alternatives>
                    </fo:page-sequence-master>
            </fo:layout-master-set>
            <fo:page-sequence master-reference="sequence">
                    <fo:static-content flow-name="fheader" >
                            <fo:block text-align="center" font-size="14pt"
                            font-family="Times New Roman">
                                    <fo:inline>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="/obj-xml/object/attribute[name='BUYER_NAME']/value"/>
                            </fo:inline>
                            </fo:block>
                    </fo:static-content>
                    <fo:flow flow-name="body">
                            <xsl:call-template name="report"/>
                    </fo:flow>
            </fo:page-sequence>
</fo:root>
</xsl:template>
                        <xsl:template name="report">
                               <!-- some code here -->
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When I try to transform my XML file using with XSL and FOP inot PDF it's looks ok, but when i try to transform into RTF there is no any headers.
I can't figure out why.

Comment: ["*RTF output is currently unmaintained and lacks many features compared to other output formats*"](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/1.0/output.html#rtf). So I suppose you should keep the expectations low.

Comment: @mzjn Thank you, I'll search a way around.